# Should I disable MySQL strict mode?

Tags: php, mysql, strict-mode

I have been working on a site that had MySQL strict mode enabled. One person had a long user agent string that was logged in our log table and unfortunately the user agent string exceeded the limit for the column and thus caused a warning. The data was not inserted at all.

To avoid such troubles, should I disable the MySQL strict mode or should I come up with something on my own (I'm using PHP)?

Comment: You could check for the string's length on application level before inserting it.

Comment: @Pekka: How would you do it reasonably? I don't want to be calling methods everywhere on the software.

Comment: well, you presumably have to escape the incoming data anyway somewhere. A `substr()` there would work and not add too much clutter. If your application works with strict mode otherwise (which is great) I'd go that road and leave the mode as it is

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Validate the data before inserting it into your database. If a string is too big to fit in your table, either your column is too narrow, or the data is invalid. You need to decide whether you truncate it before storing it, do some error reporting, or both.

Do **not** turn off the safety features of your DBMS, that's the completely wrong thing to do.

Comment: I wish you could put more bold on that "not". And it would be nice if you could turn MySQL's strictness up to 11.

Comment: I wasn't under the impression that the server mode is a safety feature. Although I guess it depends on your definition of safety feature

Comment: @ChrisWue: I'd call "not silently mangling your data" a safety feature.

Comment: From my point of view, the DBMS should reject invalid data. Always. Not sometimes [inserts adjusted values for invalid or missing values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables). I don't like magic happening. But you are also correct, the application can be coded to take this fact into account.

Answer (score 5):

Would you rather have your data silently truncated (possibly leading to broken data) or would you at least like to know that you have a problem?

I'd recommend leaving strict mode enabled and bounds checking your data in your PHP. Your PHP application knows, or at least should know, what to do with a string that's too long. If you turn off strict mode and leave that decision to MySQL then MySQL will silently truncate your strings and you will end up with a database full of garbage.

Changing and fixing code is easy, fixing broken data is often impossible.

If you disable strict mode, you'll end up with strange problems like this:

> [VARCHAR(4) storing more characters than four](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023601/479863)

Answer (score 1):

Well it's up to you try it with strict mode disabled and see how things work, I've never had an issue with it disabled but be careful.

However, if long user agents are the only issue with strict mode and you don't visually read them than I recommend just hashing your UA's or increasing the field length.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a need to do so, failing queries, and you do not have knowledge or budget to fix it - then yes.

If anyone is asking this is how to disable strict mode properly, just by adding this in MySQL config:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
innodb_strict_mode=0
```