# Changing MySQL mode per session

Tags: php, mysql, restriction, strict

I have a developer who is supporting an old application asking me to change our  MySQL mode globally away from strict - however we have several other databases on the same server that apparently require strict mode.

I believe it's possible to change mode at session level and I've tried the following code to do it.

```
session_start();

include_once("./includes/conn.php");
mysql_query("SET SESSION sql_mode = ''");
```

But this doesn't seem to work - testing the mode reports back the global and session values are the same.

```
session User : name
session Security : 27478239

MySQL server version : 5.5.5-10.0.23-MariaDB
GLOBAL : STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
SESSION : STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Is it possible to change SQL mode at session level (or database level) and if so how can this be achieved?

Comment: please stop using mysql_ functions and start using msyqli or pdo!

Comment: Yes, [that's the syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting). How exactly does it fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: @davejal this is an app that dates from 2001, the developer and I are  supporting it under sufferance and it will soon be replaced by a properly maintained tool. In the meantime I have to figure something out.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if I use SET SESSION sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' in login.php, then modetest.php (which just displays the settings) shows GLOBAL : STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
SESSION : STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

Comment: Well, you have to read back the session value (not the global one) and you have to do it from the same session.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry the paste didn't come out well - the first value is the global setting and the second the session setting - they come out the same

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having with the strict mode? Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5528449/36649600) question and check if you need to turn it off or if you have another problem. Here it is explicitly said not to turn it off. So rather solve the actual problem your having

Comment: \you are reading results from another session than the one you just set.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and share all the relevant code, not just its output?

Comment: @davejal this whole point of asking this question is to solve the problem at the level its occurring rather than altering a global setting.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have added the report to the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not saying you should do it at global level, but what's the reason to disable it? One reason could be because of annoying warnings and others because of data not being inserted in the db, depending on what the actual problem is you could have other solutions then to disable the sql_mode...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [two syntaxes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html) (well, [actually three](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html)) to change a session value, all of which should be equivalent:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode = '';
SET @@sql_mode = '';
```

To read the value back:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

Of course, since it is a session value:

- It won't affect the global setting
- It won't survive past current session
- It won't leak to other sessions

Comment: This seems to get us half way, but the change does not hold. If we run the test file it still displays the same for global and session.

Comment: Is it possible that you are running wrong verification code or you're doing it from another session? You are kind of reluctant when it comes to that :-?